# Fetch records according to non null value from mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find the first row which have "Lot No_" not null

Here is my `MYSQL` table

Serial No_  Lot No_ Entry No_
A19085A0000555      57142522
A19085A0000555      57143413
A19085A0000555      57143437
A19085A0000555      57171514
A19085A0000555      57171515
A19085A0000555      57183612
A19085A0000555      57183613
A19085A0000555      57192437
A19085A0000555  8829H   57221798
A19085A0000555  8829H   57251159
A19085A0000555  8829H   57280520
A19085A0000555  8829H   57309881
A19085A0000555  8829H   57339242
A19085A0000555  8829H   57368603
A19085A0000555  8829H   57397964
A19085A0000555  8829H   57427325
A19085A0000555  8829H   57456686
A19085A0000555  8829H   57486047
A19085A0000556      57515408
A19085A0000556      57544769
A19085A0000556      57574130
A19085A0000556      57603491
A19085A0000556  3432H   57632852
A19085A0000556  3432H   57662213
A19085A0000556  3432H   57691574
A19085A0000556  3432H   57720935
A19085A0000556  3432H   57750296
A19085A0000556  3432H   57779657

Output should be below thanks in advance

Serial No_  Lot No_ Entry No_
A19085A0000555  8829H   57221798
A19085A0000556  3432H   57632852

`Entry No_`

Comment: When you say "first," there needs to be one or more columns which determines the order in the sample table you showed us.  So, what is that column?  Also, can you show sample data for which there is more than one non `NULL` value per group?

Comment: In your question you only want first non null value and in your description you want two ENTRY NO_ values

Comment: Sorry for post before, I am new in here. So please see last edited list. And please consider I have 300,000 rows on my table. On table above three colomns (Serial No, Entry No, Lot No) that i want to eveluate. So I need to group serial nos and find first not null Lot No and get Entry No. So I had to know on which entry no first time the Lot No populated

Comment: @swo Try my answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Tim, Rohit and DineshDB thanks for your answers. Actually question should be like I recently edited. Please consider there are over 300,000 values on table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below way -

```
select entryNo as Entry_No
from tablename
where lotNo is not null
```

Comment: This happens to work with the OP's sample data, but might fail if a given lot number have more than one non `NULL` value.

Comment: This will return only the max entry number but output should be aggregate both value ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select `Entry No_` as Entry_No
from tablename
where NULLIF(`Lot No_`,'') is not null
```

OR

```
select `Entry No_` as Entry_No
from tablename
where LENGTH(`Lot No_`) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually sorry for lack of data. This was my first post so I will get used to. Here stackoverflow I found many answers to my problems. But for this one, maybe there is but I could not found any similar. Please see how I figured out my problem. I have joined same table and use ">" to found first populated row. Thanks anyway.

```
SELECT
D.[Entry No_]
,D.[Serial No_]
,D.[Lot No_]
,D.[Document No_]
,D.[Entry Type]
,D.[Posting Date]
,D.[Item No_]
FROM [DB.Item Ledger Entry] AS D WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN [DB.Item Ledger Entry] AS E WITH (NOLOCK) ON D.[Entry No_] = E.[Entry No_] AND D.[Entry No_] > E.[Entry No_]              
WHERE D.[Serial No_] IN (               
                SELECT
                A.[Serial No_]

                FROM [DB.Item Ledger Entry] AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [DB.Item] AS C WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.[Item No_] = C.No_ 
                WHERE A.[Open] = 1 AND C.[User Defined Text 6] = 'MAMUL' AND C.[Global Item Type Code] = 'IOL' 
                )
                AND D.[Entry Type] = 6 AND D.[Lot No_] <> ''
                ORDER BY D.[Entry No_]
```